# How can I integrate OWIN authentication middleware with a WebAPI MessageHandler stack?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a WebAPI 2.2 application and I set a stack of custom MessageHandlers at startup via configuration (e.g. `config.MessageHandlers.Add()`). I don't want to move away from using MessageHandlers for my pipeline, but would like to use some of the security implementations found in `Microsoft.Owin.Security`. How can I integrate Owin middleware with my MessageHandlers so that my pipeline is preserved as-is but the Owin security middleware is used for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put OWIN middleware into the WebApi piepline, but you can put them in front of it. If you're running outside of IIS then it's already recommended to run WebApi on top of OWIN/Katana like this: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/WebApi/Startup.cs

Inside of IIS you can run OWIN/Katana in front of WebApi just like you would in front of MVC, where you set the two up independently and OWIN runs first. There are already templates in Visual Studio that set this up for you.

Comment: Sounds good. So I could set up my owin auth middleware first, followed by webapi: `app.use(auth1); app.use(auth2); app.use(webapi)`. A followup question then: will the MessageHandlers have access to the identity resolved by the Owin middleware (e.g. through RequestContext.Principal)?

Comment: Yes. See http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.Owin/OwinHttpRequestContext.cs and http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.Owin/HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.cs for the integration code.